# What is the fastest way to deserialize string into scala.xml.Elem?

Tags: xml, scala

Scala seems to be very good at serializing `scala.xml.Elem` (on my machine it performs approximately 150k per seconds), however deserialization seems to be quite slow (10k per second) using `XML.loadString`

What is the fastest alternative?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst its not an answer to faster scala.xml.Elem deserializing [Scales Xml](https://github.com/chris-twiner/scalesXml) performs very well with a [far lower memory usage](http://scala-scales.googlecode.com/svn/sites/scales/scales-xml_2.9.2/0.4.4/MemoryOptimisation.html).  It provides a large range of functionality that's not present in the default library either.

Scales lets you configure the trade-offs between significantly lower memory usage and parsing performance.  The default aims to strike a great balance.